# slideToggle doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with this piece of code:
HTML

```
       <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer ridiculus pellentesque Nunc libero Lorem. Auctor vel eget Donec adipiscing urna ullamcorper tincidunt enim auctor Vivamus. Pede wisi semper Praesent Sed non orci elit Integer dis et. Sed eu diam vitae et nibh eu interdum dui Nulla suscipit. Non tristique id elit at tempor Curabitur malesuada.</p>
       <span class="hidden fullArticle">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer felis urna consectetuer Vivamus         sapien. Auctor nibh vel Fusce tortor habitant penatibus mattis hendrerit tincidunt Nullam. Et ac laoreet quis porta Sed adipiscing quis Nulla justo nibh. In ut Vestibulum tortor ligula dolor dis platea quis malesuada Nam. Eget leo augue sociis Sed Curabitur turpis    Nulla condimentum tortor magnis. Cursus suscipit faucibus ipsum sed.</p>
       </span>
       <p class="link"><a href="#">Show full article</a></p>
```

jquery JavaScript

```
    $(function() {

  /* hide full articles*/

  $(".hidden").hide();
  $("span.hidden").removeClass("hidden");

  /* showing and hiding of full articles */
  $(".link a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = $(this);
    var article = $(this).parent().prev("span");
    article.slideToggle(1000, function(){
      if (anchor.text() == "Show full article")
        anchor.text("Hide article");
      else
        anchor.text("Show full article"); 
    });    
  });  

});
```

The result should be that when I click the anchor "Show full article" then the span before it with class fullArticle should slideToggle and the text in anchor should change to "Hide article".

After that when I click the "Hide article" it should slideToggle again and change the text to "Show full article".

But something is wrong and it isn't working properly. Can you give me some solution? Thank for your help. There is also jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zYAcB/18/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at - http://jsfiddle.net/zYAcB/18/

I edited your javascript:

```
$(function () {
    /* hide full articles*/

    $(".hidden").hide();

    /* showing and hiding of full articles */
    $(".link a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var anchor = $(this);
        var article = $(this).parent().prev("div");
        article.slideToggle(1000);
        if (anchor.text() == "Show full article") {
            anchor.text("Hide article");
        } else {
            anchor.text("Show full article");
        }
    });
});
```

And took out the `.hidden { display: none; }` bit in the css.

As an aside - it isn't semantically correct to have block level elements like `<p>` inside an inline element like `<span>` so I changed it to a `<div>` instead.

Comment: Still doesn't work. When I click "Show full article" it shows it but not slide. And After that when I click "Hide article" it slideToggle and the slideToggle again immediately.

Comment: Huups. Sorry I didn't realize what you were writing about that div. When I change the span to div it works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It works properly if you just change your `<span>` element to `<div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/zYAcB/30/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that a `span` is `inline` and you need a `block` level element for `slide` to work. You can set your `span` to `display:block` or you can replace it with a `div`.